# Conditional expression using booleans produces unexpected result

Tags: c, boolean

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {        
    int num;
    int i;
    int prime = true;

    // omitted for brevity

    if (prime = true) {
        printf("The number is prime\n");    
    }
    else {
        printf("The number isn't prime\n");
    }
}
```

I'm trying to write a program that checks to see if a number is prime, but it always says that the number is prime. The answer is probably blindingly obvious, but i'm a huge noob.

Comment: Your compiler is shouting at you, isn't it?

Comment: Please edit the subject of your question to make it something useful. "How do I fix this" is absolutely useless for future readers of this site searching for an answer to their problems. Thanks. Also, if you turn on compiler hints and warnings, it would tell you **exactly** what the problem is here.

Comment: Notice that even once you fixed the obvious mistake, your code still doesn’t work because your algorithm for the primality check is simply wrong.

Comment: @KonradRudolph at the risk of making myself look like an idiot, what's wrong with the algorithm here?

Comment: @JasonD It says 2 is not a prime.

Answer (score 4):

At least,

```
if (prime = true)
```

should be

```
if (prime == true)
```

,but better just

```
if (prime)
```

Otherwise the result of the assignment `prime = true` is the assigned value, which is true.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (prime = true)
```

should be

```
if (prime == true)
```

instead.

`=` is the assignment operator, you are looking for the equality operator `==`.

Make sure you compile your program with warnings enabled and that you fix all the warnings in your code. A decent program should not generate any warning.

Comment: No, wrong. It should be `if (prime)`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph or `if (prime != false)` if we want to be verbose, but certainly not `if (prime == true)`.

Comment: @H2CO3 I don’t see either method as acceptable.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Given that C regards the value 0 as the unique false value, comparing against an explicit 0 of the proper type can be useful to help those who are reading the code. For example, a comparison against `NULL` makes it obvious that a variable is a pointer.

Comment: @H2CO3 Comparison against `NULL` or `false` is semantically a fundamentally different thing from comparing to a boolean literal. Although C’s type system doesn’t make the distinction, the latter is simply a nonsensical operation. If you insist on writing `x != false` you should logically write `(x != false) != false`. And so on. Comparing against a boolean value is simply one step too many in a never-ending runaway process.